# Generator concatenation

Tags: python, concatenation, generator

There're list on generator, each gen generate list. So, we have list of list... Close enough, but not.

So, i would like to convert list of the list to list concatenation. For pure list it's simple `sum(list_of_list,[])` But for gens it throws `TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "generator") to list`

How it perfectly do for generators?
Need one-line code.

Сause two-line code already exist

```
res = []
[res.extend(x) for x in list_of_gens]
```

Comment: "**Need** one-line code" – code golf homework?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I've fully understood your question, but I think this is what you're looking for:

```
sum([[item for item in generator] for generator in list_of_gens], [])
```

This takes each generator and makes a list from it and then uses sum to concatenate those lists.

Comment: how match it cost? Even my decision looks time-expensive... And this one?

Comment: I couldn't get your two-line code to work so can't compare. For me it returns a list of `[None, None, None]`. Perhaps because the generator I tested with wasn't also an iterator. Afraid I don't know enough to say which method is quicker in general. Might be best to ask another question if you're looking for the most efficient code rather than a one-line solution.